# Get mouse position in GeoExt

Tags: geoext

The title says it all. I'm using GeoExt as part of OpenGeo Suite. I would like to display the current mouse coordinates.

Update: I was getting confused as to what parts of the code are GeoExt and which parts are OpenLayers.

Here's some code. mapPanel is a GeoExt object. mapPanel.map is an OpenLayers object.

```
var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({ 
    // etc.
});

mapPanel.map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
```

Comment: Have similar problem but I don quite Have similar problem but I don´t quite get the provided answer ...
I´m building a OpenGeo app using suite SDK and so far I haven´t been able to find a way to add the Mouse Position to my code.
The code I´m using does not have a GeoExt.MapPanel, instead I have var app = new gxp.Viewer({ portalConfig: {}, tools:[], //etc }); to be honest I have no idea where or how I add the openLayer.Control into these code so any idea woulb be much apreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As GeoExt is using OpenLayers for the map interface, you could use its MousePosition contol :

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mouse-position.html